# python variable as a string

Tags: python, python-3.x

When i run the following i get the output i require from print. Then i am trying ti insert the results into my create file. I can input a property.text value in there and it works fine or just 'string' but when i try to call the results in there it just dosen't do anything.

```
alarms = system.alarm.queryStatus(state=["ActiveUnacked", "ClearAcked"])

for alarm in alarms: 
print alarm.getName(), alarm.getState()
```

result

```
Dryer 7 Temp low Cleared, Acknowledged
Dryer 10 Temp High Cleared, Acknowledged
Dryer 5 Burner Fault Cleared, Acknowledged
```

when i run this

```
alarms = system.alarm.queryStatus(state=["ActiveUnacked", "ClearAcked"])
for alarm in alarms: 
alarm1 = alarm.getName(), alarm.getState()

my_file = open('D:\send_file3.txt','w')
my_file.write('from call import Client\n')
my_file.write('account_sid = "test"\n')
my_file.write('auth_token = "test"\n')
my_file.write('client = Client(account_sid, auth_token)\n')
my_file.write('message =client.api.account.messages.create(to="+6140000000", 
from_="+614000000000", body=" ')
my_file.write(alarm1)
my_file.write(' ")') 
my_file.close()
```

text file output

it writes all lines to

```
body="
```

then blank. If i change alarm1 to 'hello'

i get `body="hello "`).

What i want to achieve is

```
body="Dryer 7 Temp low Cleared, Acknowledged Dryer 10 Temp High Cleared, Acknowledged Dryer 5 Burner Fault Cleared, Acknowledged"
```

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Use String formatting for this task. [More info](https://pyformat.info/)

```
 alarms = system.alarm.queryStatus(state=["ActiveUnacked", "ClearAcked"])
    for alarm in alarms: 
        alarm1 = alarm.getName(), alarm.getState()
        my_file = open('D:\send_file3.txt','w')
        my_file.write('from call import Client\n')
        my_file.write('account_sid = "test"\n')
        my_file.write('auth_token = "test"\n')
        my_file.write('client = Client(account_sid, auth_token)\n')
        my_file.write('message=client.api.account.messages.create(to="+6140000000", from_="+614000000000", body=\"{}\"').format(alarm1)
        my_file.close()
```

Comment: You could improve your answer by giving a brief explanation.

Comment: A good answer can not be just code, you must have an explanation of what is proposed.

Answer (score 0):

Since `alarm` is not a string/text, you can't write it directly to the file. you can achieve this by putting `alarm.getName()` and `alarm.getState()` inside a list and joining them as string using a delimiter `","`. Then you can write it to a file

```
my_file = open('D:\send_file3.txt','w')
my_file.write('from call import Client\n')
my_file.write('account_sid = "test"\n')
my_file.write('auth_token = "test"\n')
my_file.write('client = Client(account_sid, auth_token)\n')
my_file.write('message =client.api.account.messages.create(to="+6140000000", 
from_="+614000000000", body=" ')
for alarm in alarms: 
    myfile.write(",".join([alarm.getName(), alarm.getState()]))
```

Comment: You could improve your answer by giving a brief explanation.